# why post_class() function apply css classes to all other files in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I use the post_class() function to add a custom class of CSS like width and display property. But it applied to all other files like the about page, contact page. I tried to use the WordPress class instead of using the class attribute of HTML.
I have referred wordpress.org.
I thought post_class can use for WordPress predefined class and also for adding custom classes.
It's a right or wrong method. Please suggest if anyone knows, where to use the post_class()? and it is ok to use post_class() for adding custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a right way.
you can add your own class in `post_class()` function